# How to create an arraylist with enums

Tags: java

I have one class:

```
package business;

public class Card {
    public enum Suit{SPADE, CLUB, HEART, DIAMOND};
    public enum Rank{JACK, KING, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, ACE, QUEEN}

    private String Suit;
    private String Rank;

    public Card(String suit, String rank) {
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.Rank = rank;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return Rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return Suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getRank() + " of " + getSuit();
    }
}
```

And I have another class:

```
package data;

import business.Hand;
import business.Card;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {

    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public ArrayList<Card> get32Cards() {

        **deck.add(new Card("Spades", "Jack"));**

        Collections.shuffle(deck); //this shuffles the deck

        return deck;
    }
}
```

How do I add an element to an `ArrayList` so that it looks like the one in bold?
I previously just made them strings, which is why there is 'private string suit' and 'private string rank' there.

They are also in separate packages, business, and data

Comment: `deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.JACK))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use enum with String value like:

```
//Card
public class Card {

    public enum Suit {
        SPADE("Spades"), CLUB("Club"), HEART("Heart"), DIAMOND("Diamond");
        private String suitText;

        private Suit(String suitText) {
            this.suitText = suitText;
        }

        public String getSuitText() {
            return suitText;
        }

    };

    public enum Rank {
        JACK("Jack"), KING("King"), SEVEN("Seven"), EIGHT("Eight"), NINE("Nine"), TEN("Ten"), ACE("Ace"), QUEEN(
                "Queen");
        private String rankText;

        public String getRankText() {
            return rankText;
        }

        private Rank(String rankText) {
            this.rankText = rankText;
        }

    }

    private String suit;
    private String rank;

    public Card(String suit, String rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getRank() + " of " + getSuit();
    }
}


//Deck
public class Deck {

    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public ArrayList<Card> get32Cards() {

//       add Card with Enum value
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADE.getSuitText(), Rank.JACK.getRankText()));
        Collections.shuffle(deck); //this shuffles the deck

        return deck;

    }
}
```

Hope this help.